# JavaFX creating a textField event handler using lambda expressions that reacts to s specific key (enter)?

Tags: events, javafx, lambda

So, I got this that reacts to any key

```
TextField resultado = new TextField();
resultado.setOnKeyPressed(e -> System.out.println("It works!"))
```

But Would like it to react to return key only.

Anyone?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
TextField resultado = new TextField();
resultado.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
});
```

Note that `TextField`s also fire action events when the enter key is pressed:

```
TextField resultado = new TextField();
resultado.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("It works!"))
```

Comment: You are righ, and also right on "Note that TextFields also fire action events when the enter key is pressed:"  This will be enough. Tanhk you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The way to find out the answers to these sorts of questions yourself is to delve into the Oracle documentation.

Thus, you are using method `setOnKeyPressed()` and this gives you a `KeyEvent`.

When you look up the instance methods on the `KeyEvent` class you find methods like `getCharacter()` and `getCode()`.

You can then play around with these methods to figure out how they work and how you can use them.

In this way, you have then answered your own question and probably learnt more than you would just by posting a question here and waiting for someone to answer it. :)